# Search a specific string in lines and than do a substr at this point in PERL

Tags: string, perl, indexing, substr

I would like to search in a line for a string. After I found this string, I want to do a substr in that in order get ID. Here an example.

String `Testname Testfile 21345 Anfragekennziffer 4519349 Teststring`

- so, in this case I would like the script to catch the string "Anfragekennziffer" and to get the ID, which is here: `4519349`.

I wrote a script so far, that get me the Ids but only if "Anfragekennziffer" is at the beginning in a line. E.g:

```
line 1 "Anfragekennziffer4586268" result: "4586268"
line 2 "Anfragekennziffer5686797" result: "5686797"
```

E.G.

An input file could have the following content:

```
da adad Anfragekennziffer 6797456
dadad  Anfragekennziffer6453914
dasdssss Anfragekennziffer6797433
dddsaaa Anfragekennziffer6609572
aaa Anfragekennziffer2435282
Anfragekennziffer 1234567
Anfragekennziffer21415666
```

My script (see below) would get the following result:

```
'nnziffer6','nziffer645','ennziffer6','nnziffer66','ffer243528','1234567','21415666'
```

So, I would like the script to start at "Anfragekennziffer" and get me the ID - npo matter where Anfragekennziffer is located in the line.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $Source = "Anfragekennziffer.txt";
my $SQL1 = "SQL_Confluence_Tabelle.txt";
my $SQL2 = "SQL_Provider_Antwort.txt";
my $time = localtime;

print "\n";
print "Local date and time: $time\n";
print "\n";
print "IDs wurden übertragen.\n";
print "Folgende SQL-Statements wurden erstellt:\n";
print "\n";
print "'SQL_Confluence_Tabelle'\n";
print "'SQL_Provider_Antwort'\n";
print "\n";

open(QUELLE, "$Source") or die "Open failed:$!";
open(ZIEL1, ">$SQL1") or die "Open failed:$!";
open(ZIEL2, ">$SQL2") or die "Open failed:$!";

my $ids;
my $weg;

while(my $row = <QUELLE>)
{
    if ($row =~m/Anfragekennziffer/)
    {
        $row=substr($row,17,10); #gebe nur IDs aus
        $row=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; #löscht Leerzeichen
        $ids=$ids."'".$row."',"; #kumuliere IDs
        $ids=~ s/\r|\n//g;
    }
}
$weg=chop($ids);

print ZIEL1 "$ids";

print ZIEL2 "$ids";
close(QUELLE); 
close(ZIEL1); 
close(ZIEL2);
```

Would be great if someone  would have an idea!

THANKS!

Comment: So you have database dumps and want to perform text search on them? Why?

Comment: its not about the datbase dumps. getting emails from other people. There fore i wrote this script in order to get IDs faster (e.g. in a SQL query). Therefore, I just dont want to prepare the "list" in lines, that "Anfragekennziffer" is at the start in a row. I would kike to search for it, and than do a substr. 


e.g. "yszadszadjadkak Anfragkennziffer 123458 yaidgqfoiqhfoqo" - so I expect here the ID 123458, cause I found "Anfragekennziffer".

Comment: done. maybe its better to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the numbers after the keyword `Anfragekennziffer` is easiest done using a regular expression that also matches the number and captures it:

```
my @ids;
while(my $row = <QUELLE>)
{
    if ($row =~ m/Anfragekennziffer\s*(\d+)/)
    {
        push @ids, $1;
    }
}
print join ",", @ids;
```

If you feel more comfortable using `substr`, then the [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function can give you the position where your keyword starts in the string and you can try to extract the number from there:

```
my @ids;
while(my $row = <QUELLE>)
{
    if (my $pos = index('Anfragekennziffer', $row))
    {
        push @ids, substr( $row, $pos + length('Anfragekennziffer'), 10 );
    }
}
print join ",", @ids;
```

This approach is far more fragile than the approach directly matching the number.

In both cases, instead of building a string, I've switched to accumulating the information in an array (`@ids`) and then printing that array at the end using the [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function. Keeping lists as arrays helps your code stay flexible in the case you want to do something else with the data later on.

Comment: great, it works fine. Thank you very much!
Now, I am trying to aggregate the ids as follows:

e.g.: '59092','1491915',11851'

Tried this so far (see below), but it retunrs only one ID. (The last one)

`my @ids;
while(my $row = <QUELLE>)
{
    if ($row =~ m/Anfragekennziffer\s*(\d+)/)
    {
        push @ids, $1;
  @ids="'".$1."',";
    }
}
print join ",", @ids;

print ZIEL1 "@ids";

print ZIEL2 "@ids";`

Comment: No no - `@ids` already has the list of the ids. Don't do string concatenation with it. Just `push` items onto that list, and in the end, `print` the `join`ed list to your files. Don't do `print "@ids"` unless you want the list to be space-separated.

Comment: Thank you! Gonna try it tomorrow! :)